# how to adjust multi line text size based on the container in flutter

Tags: flutter

if the value of customeHeight and customeWidth changes then the child value also should change. At the same time text size has to be fitted based on the parent container height and width.

fontSize has to increase and decrease.

// Parent class

```
Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0, top: 60.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: Container(
              height: customeHeight,
              width: customeWidth,
              child: widget.child,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 4.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
              )
              ),


    ),
```

==========================================================================

//child class
//this will return as child to its parent

```
return LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    print("container size $constraints");
                    print("no of character $noOfChar");
                    // double maxSize =
                    //     (constraints.maxWidth * constraints.maxHeight) / 3000;
                    // print("maxsize $maxSize");
                    return FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: LimitedBox(
                        maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight + noOfChar,
                        maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth + noOfChar,
                        child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          // maxLines: null,
                          onChanged: (str) {
                            setState(() {
                              noOfChar = str.length;
                            });
                          },
                          autofocus: true,
                          enabled: true,
                          // focusNode: myFocusNode,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30.0,
                              color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontFamily: widget.fontType),
                          decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                              hintText: widget.change),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  })
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a container without fixed height and use Maxline attribute to support multiline.

```
 Widget MultilineText(){
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 16.0, 8.0),
      child: addTextView("Something something",15.0),
      ),
    );
  }
 Widget addTextView(String data, double fontSize){
    return  new Text(
        data,
        maxLines: 1000,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black87,
            fontSize: fontSize,
            fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
        )
 }
```

Comment: This is not answering the question. He wants the font size to change dynamically depending on the space available.

Comment: I give a solution how he can adjust multi line text size based on the container in flutter. He can change font creating a function which will return text Widget. FYI, I updated my answer.I think now it is ok.